# why do I get syntax error of not a group by expression in below query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a schema of `emp` table as `(empno , ename , hiredate ,sal,job)` and I have the query as :

Find the total annual salary to distribute job wise in the year 81.

I wrote the below query :

```
select job, sum(Sal*12)
from emp
group by job
having (extract(year from hiredate)) = '1981' ;
```

This query is giving output as "not a group by expression " ,please guide me in identifying the problem here .

Comment: Which dbms do you use?

Comment: I am working on Oracle10g

Comment: Then add the tags next time

Comment: `year` is not in the list of columns you group by, therefor `having` - which operates on the _groups_  - can't use that column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HAVING` is intended be used with an aggregate. `(extract(year from hiredate))='1981'` should be placed in `WHERE` clause instead.

```
select job,sum(Sal*12)
from emp
where extract(year from hiredate)=1981
group by job
```

Having is applied after aggregation and must be used if you want to filter aggregate results. There is no such requirement with where. According to your question, you are trying to capture only records from 1981. There is no point in aggregating before comparison.

Comment: But I think with group by clause we use 'having' and not 'where' clause

Comment: You can use `where` before `group by` and `having` after `group by`.

Comment: @Utsav, and? Still not equal functionality.

Comment: @jarlh - yep. I was just clarifying OP's doubt that `where` cannot be used with `group by`.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify my one doubt what is the difference in the query wherein I apply where clause with group by and having clause with group by since in both scenarios we try to filter the records with a certain constraint .

Comment: `HAVING` is applied after aggregation, `WHERE` is applied before.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming as the clause used in having is not part of group by.
Rewrite the query as 

`select job, sum(Sal * 12)
  from SO_EMP
 group by job, (extract(year from hiredate))
having(extract(year
  from hiredate)) = '1981';`